# Filtering REST API PowerBI results in Powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, powerbi, powerbi-api

I am attempting to call the "Get Groups" REST API to return a list of all the workspaces I have access to in Power BI. I want to be able to add a filter to the API call and return only the workspaces whose names have the word "email" in them. I've tried to edit the API url, but nothing seems to change the result set. Any thoughts help!

$GetWorkspaces = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/" -Method Get

I've tried the "try it" function in microsoft docs learn pages, but these urls aren't working either.

Answer (score 0):

##### Give this a try

- You can use the `$filter` query parameter to filter the workspaces by name. The `$filter` parameter supports OData filter expressions. To filter workspaces   whose names contain the word "email", you can use the following expression:

  `$filter=indexof(name,'email') ne -1`
- Here is the updated PowerShell script that includes the `$filter` parameter:
- The backtick () character is used to escape the `$character` in the `$filter` parameter so that PowerShell does not treat it as a variable.
- This script should return a list of workspaces whose names contain the word "email"

```
$GetWorkspaces = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/?`$filter=indexof(name,'email') ne -1" -Method Get
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
$GetWorkspaces = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups?%24filter=contains(name%2C%27email%27)" -Method Get
```